What is the best way to validate an uploaded file?
I'm creating a custom module where people can fill out a form to apply for a job. Of course I want to implement form validation but it goes wrong when I want to validate the uploaded file.
I can't seem to find a clear way to validate uploaded files, like anywhere. I'm trying to rely on my php knowledge but of course it is not entirely the same when it comes down to drupal.
I'm providing you guys with something I had now, which clearly doesn't work, but I would like to ask what you would say is the best way to validate uploaded files? And without installing third party modules..
What I tried:
// Validate the uploaded file
$validators = ['file_validate_extensions' => ['docx doc pdf jpg jpeg png']];
$file = file_save_upload('cv', $validators, FALSE, 0);

if (!$file) {
    // Add error message if the file isn't validated
    $form_state->setErrorByName('cv', $this->t('Uw CV heeft een niet-toegestane extensie. Probeer het opnieuw.'));
} else {
    // Set the correct file in the form state
    $form_state->setValue('cv', $file);
}

Unfortunately, file_save_upload is not recognized because it's deprecated and drupals documentation is a bit confusing to me..
Thanks in advance!

Yes, the thing that annoyes me the most is that in the form builder, I pass the file_validate_extensions which are pdf, docx en jpg. But when I want to test it by trying to upload a .txt file (which is not allowed), there are no errors and the form is submitted. That shouldn't happen.
You understand what I'm trying to achieve?

I'll try to find a way to implement this. Unless you have a link how I can do that easily?

refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24500772/drupal-validation-solution-when-using-file-upload-with-other-required-form-field for upload file validations
